# How to actually use meta tags to share data through social networks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter

So I'm trying to do a website that has multiple images with their own content and allow users to click on a dropdown next to an image and share that image and the content to: Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn, and Email.

What I've looked into is creating a separate URL for each image with it's content. Then in each page setting it's description, image, etc. in the meta tags. So on the landing page when they click to share it's actually pulling a separate page.

My question is...how do I share meta tag information to Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn, and Email?

I've tried for Twitter:

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="share-twitter sd-button share-icon no-text" href="http://twitter.com/share?text=Textgoeshere&url=https://www.landingpage.com/&hashtags=example" target="_blank" title="Click to share on Twitter"><span></span><span class="sharing-screen-reader-text">Click to share on Twitter (Opens in new window)</span></a>
```

This seems like a lot of text that I would have to then write for each image. Plus it doesn't pull the image, author, etc. Isn't there a way to grab the meta tag information to share to Twitter here?

I mean I have the meta tags present (below) but no idea how to actually use them to share.

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="Here's Twitter Card"/>
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@author"/>
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="@author"/>
<meta name="twitter:url" content="http://www.mainpage.com">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Twitter Title">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Here is the Twitter Description">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="link to image">
```

Found the following for Facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button#

Found the following for Twitter:
https://publish.twitter.com/#

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is what I'll do for you because I am not sure what answer you are looking for here. We are going to write some javacript that can do this for you.

Here you have your HTML tag. It's important that you give every div the class "twitter-input-card" and you give them an onload function of "updateCards()".

HTML here:

```
<div class="twitter-input-cards" onload="updateCards(tCard1)"> </div>
```

Now here is your js....:

```
    //this function creates your object
function twitterCards(twitterCard, twitterAuthor1, twitterAuthor2, twitterURL, twitterTitle, twitterDes, twitterImg) {
    //this will be twitter:card
    this.twitterCard = twitterCard;
    //this will be twitter:site
    this.twitterAuthor1 = twitterAuthor1;
    //this will be twitter:domain
    this.twitterAuthor2 = twitterAuthor2;
    //this will be twitter:url
    this.twitterURL = twitterURL;
    //this will be twitter:title
    this.twitterTitle = twitterTitle;
    //this will be twitter:description
    this.twitterDes = twitterDes;
    //this will be twitter:image
    this.twitterImg = twitterImg;

}


//this isn't as important but i am not familiar with twitter cards so if there are more meta tags you can define them here.
var tcard = 'twitter:card';
var tsite = 'twitter:site';
var tdomain = 'twitter:domain';
var turl = 'twitter:url';
var ttitle = 'twitter:title';
var tdes = 'twitter:description';
var timg = 'twitter:image';



//this function will update the card with information
  function  updateCards(selectCard){
    cardSelect = selectCard; 

    document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-input-cards").innerHTML = "<meta name=" + "'" + tcard + "' content = '" + twitterCard + "'/>"
    document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-input-cards").innerHTML = "<meta name=" + "'" + tsite + "' content = '" + twitterAuthor1 + "'/>"
    document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-input-cards").innerHTML = "<meta name=" + "'" + tdomain + "' content = '" + twitterAuthor2 + "'/>"
    document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-input-cards").innerHTML = "<meta name=" + "'" + turl + "' content = '" + twitterURL + "'/>"
    document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-input-cards").innerHTML = "<meta name=" + "'" + ttitle + "' content = '" + twitterTitle + "'/>"
    document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-input-cards").innerHTML = "<meta name=" + "'" + tdes + "' content = '" + twitterDes + "'/>"
    document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-input-cards").innerHTML = "<meta name=" + "'" + timg + "' content = '" + twitterImg + "'/>"


  }



//this is where you define your cards info
var tCard1 = new twitterCards (
    //this will be twitter:card
    "Here is a new card",
    //this will be twitter:site
    "here is an author",
    //this will be twitter:domain
    "here is another aurthor",
    //this will be twitter:url
    "here is the page",
    //this will be twitter:title
    "here is the title",
    //this will be twitter:description
    "here is the description",
    //this will be twitter:img
    "img.jpg"

)
```